# Connect Via Universal Serial Bus Controllers not Serial Port in C#

Tags: c#, .net, usb

I'm trying to connect a machine via USB to USB not Serial to USB. Using SerialPort class is not appropriate. Is there any way to connect using c#? I've tried to use LibUsbDotNet library but the program cannot find the machine connected in my pc.

[Using Cypress EZ USB driver to connect to the machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPnFd.png)

Can someone help me with my problem? Thanks

```
private void comboBox1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mRegDevices = UsbDevice.AllDevices;
        foreach (UsbRegistry regDevice in mRegDevices)
        {
            // add the Vid, Pid, and usb device description to the dropdown display.
            // NOTE: There are many more properties available to provide you with more device information.
            // See the LibUsbDotNet.Main.SPDRP enumeration.
            string sItem = String.Format("Vid:{0} Pid:{1} {2}",
                                         regDevice.Vid.ToString("X4"),
                                         regDevice.Pid.ToString("X4"),
                                         regDevice.FullName);
            comboBox1.Items.Add(sItem);
        }
    }
```

The code above is from the sample code from LibUsbDotNet. To list all available devices in a ComboBox but nothing shows.

Comment: Show us what you “tried to use” and explain why you think “the program cannot find the machine”.

Comment: @DourHighArch I've edited my post. I'm new in working with machines or any device. Can you help me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code below will list all Universal Serial Bus Controllers that are detected by your PC.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Management;

namespace CsharpUSBConnetctionInfo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (var usbDevice in usbDevices)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Device ID: {0}, PNP Device ID: {1}, Description: {2}", usbDevice.DeviceID, usbDevice.PnpDeviceID, usbDevice.Description);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static List<USBDeviceInfo> GetUSBDevices()
        {
            List<USBDeviceInfo> devices = new List<USBDeviceInfo>();

            ManagementObjectCollection collection;

            using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Select * From Win32_USBHub")) collection = searcher.Get();
            foreach (var device in collection)
            {
                devices.Add(new USBDeviceInfo(
                    (string)device.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID"),
                    (string)device.GetPropertyValue("PNPDeviceID"),
                    (string)device.GetPropertyValue("Description")
                    ));
            }

            collection.Dispose();
            return devices;

        }
    }

    class USBDeviceInfo
    {
        public USBDeviceInfo(string deviceID, string pnpDeivceID, string description)
        {
            this.DeviceID = deviceID;
            this.PnpDeviceID = pnpDeivceID;
            this.Description = description;
        }

        public string DeviceID
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public string PnpDeviceID
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public string Description
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
    }
}
```